# stop visit counter with dynamic ip address

Tags: php, ip-address

I have a script for counting visitors.

I need to avoid counting my own visit.

```
if ($ip == "127.0.0.1" or $ip == "31.176.166.1") {return false;}
```

But I found that my ip address is dynamic.

Is there any way to stop counting my visits in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a cookie for yourself and then check to see if that cookie exists. If so, don't count yourself.

```
// on the cookie setting page
setcookie("is_me", 1, strtotime('+10 years'));

// code to check to see if it is you
if ($_COOKIE['is_me']) {return false;}
```

The easiest way to do this is to create a page only you know about, set the cookie there, and verify it works (and then delete the page if that is the only computer you will use to view your site).

Comment: John, thanks a lot. btw I saw the first line of you answer about five seconds after clicking on submit button :)

Comment: Yeah, the solution came to me quickly :)

Answer (score 1):

A common way to achieve this is to create a cookie with prolonged expiration for your site in your browser, and do not count the visits from whoever attaches this cookie to the requests. So your if would become something like:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['admin'])) 
     return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

at first get your own ip

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

now save it as cookie
setcookie("my ip", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], strtotime('+10 years'));

if anyone visit your website check that is it matched with your ip then

`resturn false`

Comment: sadu, I think this will not work, because my IP is dynamic, i.e. it is changed each time I turn on the comp.

Comment: you can save your ip address in cookie each time when the project run in your browser then you can check that if it matched or not.

Comment: but, in this case, how can I set cookie for me, and prevent another user to set it for him?

Comment: you know the ip address can't be assigned for more user at a time